# Highligh the values, where colors matched in same row in

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with values from B2:AF7 highlighted with three different colors.
I used VBA code for highlight values, (code not mentioned in this post).

My question is:
How can highlight with separate color, where three colors matched in same row.
(for ref see picture: columns 11, 14, 15 and 4th row was matched with three different colors, I would like to highlight those values with separate color)

I wrote following code, but it is not working.

Thanks for your valuable time.

```
Dim r as range
Dim i as integer
set r = range("b2:af7")

For i = 2 To 31
    if r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 and  r.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 and    r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 then
        msgbox r.address
        r.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    else
        msgbox "Row not found"
    end if
Next i
```

[image]

Comment: Your code example does not select the cells with the same color, it tries to select cells with different colors and make them one color. Please clarify what you are trying to do. Are the three cells connected or separated? What if you have more then 3 cells with the same color? What is criteria used in your code to select the values that you color? It would be easier to color each cell based on the original criteria to select the cells to color.

Comment: What would happen if eg column 17 in this row would be red. Then there would be 3 possible matches (11;14;15), (14;15;17) and (15;17;21). So you would need to define a rule for how this case should be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### An approach using Regular Expressions

If you convert your color indices of the data range …

[image]

… into a sequence of color indices like below:

```
0000000003030600000000000000000
0006000000000000000000000000000
0400300000004000460000000000000
0000003000300460000046000000000
0000003330000000000000000000000
```

you can use a Regular Expression to find the color patterns `346`, `364`, `436`, `463`, `634` and `643`.

I used the following pattern to ignore zeros in between:

```
3{1}0*4{1}0*6{1}|3{1}0*6{1}0*4{1}|4{1}0*3{1}0*6{1}|4{1}0*6{1}0*3{1}|6{1}0*3{1}0*4{1}|6{1}0*4{1}0*3{1}
```

With the match as result you will get `Match.FirstIndex` which represents the start column of the pattern and `Match.Length` which represents the length of the match.

So with …

```
DataRange.Cells(iRow, Match.FirstIndex + 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=Match.Length)
```

… you retrieve the range of the current row that matched the pattern.

#### Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindColorPattern()
    Dim DataRange As Range 'define data range
    Set DataRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:AF7")
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To DataRange.Rows.Count 'loop row wise
        'read color indices into an array
        Dim PatternArray As Variant
        ReDim PatternArray(1 To DataRange.Columns.Count)
        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = 1 To DataRange.Columns.Count
            PatternArray(iCol) = DataRange(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex
            If PatternArray(iCol) <> 3 And PatternArray(iCol) <> 4 And PatternArray(iCol) <> 6 Then PatternArray(iCol) = 0
        Next iCol
        
        'find pattern
        Dim Matches As Object
        Set Matches = MatchPattern(Join(PatternArray, vbNullString))
        
        'mark found pattern in data range
        If Not Matches Is Nothing Then
            Dim Match As Object
            For Each Match In Matches
                With DataRange.Cells(iRow, Match.FirstIndex + 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=Match.Length)
                    'draw a border around the match
                    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlSolid
                    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 9
                    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlSolid
                    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 9
                    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlSolid
                    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).ColorIndex = 9
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlSolid
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 9
                End With
            Next Match
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub


Function MatchPattern(TextToSearch As String) As Object
    Dim RegEx As Object, Matches As Object

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegEx
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "3{1}0*4{1}0*6{1}|3{1}0*6{1}0*4{1}|4{1}0*3{1}0*6{1}|4{1}0*6{1}0*3{1}|6{1}0*3{1}0*4{1}|6{1}0*4{1}0*3{1}"
    End With

    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(TextToSearch)
    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        Set MatchPattern = Matches
    Else
        Set MatchPattern = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```